# UnicodeDecodeError when trying to read an hdf file made with python 2.7

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, hdf

I have a bunch of hdf files that I need to read in with pandas `pd.read_hdf()` but they have been saved in a python 2.7 environment. Nowadays, I'm on python 3.7, and when trying to read them with `data = pd.read_hdf('data.h5', 'data')`, I'm getting

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 6: invalid start byte
```

Now I know, those files can contain various *weird* things like *Ä* or *ö*, and `0xf6` probably is *ö*.

**So how do I read this hdf file?**

The [documentation for `read_hdf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_hdf.html?highlight=read_hdf) only specifies `mode` as a parameter, but this doesn't do anything. Apparently, this is an [old bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17540) in pandas, or rather with underlying pytables that can't be fixed. However, that is from 2017, so I wonder if that's fixed, or rather if there's a workaround that I just can't find. According to the bug report, you can also pass `enconding=''` to the reader, but that doesn't do anything when I specify `encoding='UTF8'` as suggested in the bug, or `encoding='cp1250'` which I would assume could be the culprit.

It's quite annoying to have a file format that is meant to archive data, which apparently can't be read anymore by the program that produced it after just one version step. I would be perfectly fine with just having the *ö*s garbled to `␣ý⌧` or similar fun things as usual with encoding errors, but simply not being able to read it is an issue.

Comment: Was the file generated on a Windows computer? Than you might try a cp1252 or latin1 encoding. Of course, you can also open the file with in binary mode 'rb', then you will get the raw bytes instead of (unicode) strings.

Comment: It was generated on linux, but the workflow that produced it was using a lot of csv files originating from some old windows box. `cp1252` and `latin1` also produce the same error. `mode=rb` was also my first idea, but `mode` only supports b, b+ and a.

Comment: My comment assumed that you were reading a file directly. As HDF5 is a binary format, your file is always opened as such. The conversion to unicode is done by the HDF reader. I think you will need to modify the low-level reader to solve this one, and curse the old HDF5 writer for having a cavalier attitude towards Unicode. Your file probably reports the UTF8 encoding, but uses latin1 internally--an error.

Comment: Your best bet is to open the dataset in another tool (e.g. python2 with hdf5 reader), and re-write the data ensuring that the encoding is correct.